# DatePicker cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: import, datepicker, javafx

I am writing JavaFX program. I want to use DatePicker to let a user choose a date. I've got a problem importing DatePicker. I already use a number of "javafx.scene.control.something" imports, therefore I have no idea why it is being a pain.

When I try and compile the program I get this error: 
"java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker cannot be resolved".

I checked official documentation, tried Googling the issue but I'm getting nowhere and am out of ideas. I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: What Java/JavaFX version are you using?

Comment: Java: 1.7.0_40
JavaFx: javafx.runtime.version: 2.2.60-b19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatePicker` was introduced to the API in Java 8 (see `@since` tag in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html)). You will need to update to version 8.